# Вывод элементов динамических массивов

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int num; //размер массива
    int i = 0;

    int* index;//Указатели на массивы с данными
    char* user;
    char* name;

    printf("К-во ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Введите: Текст,число,текст\n");

    //динамическое выделение памяти
    index = (int*) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    user = (char*) malloc(num * sizeof(char));
    name = (char*) malloc(num * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s,%d,%s", &name[i], &index[i], &user[i]);
    }

    printf("%s", user[0]);

    free(index);
    free(user);
    free(name);

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод введенных результатов `printf("%s", user[0]);` аварийно завершает выполнение программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде две основные неприятности.

1 - неверное выделение памяти. Строка в С - это указатель на массив. Т.е. массив строк - это *массив указателей на массивы*. Ниже я привожу исправленный код, думаю, все станет понятнее. Соответственно, передавать в `scanf` для строки надо указатель на нее, каковым в нашем случае (*массива указателей на массивы символов*) является просто указатель на массив символов, т.е. просто `name[i]` или просто `user[i]`.

2 - `%s` считывает все до пробела, так что у вас при вводе, скажем,

```
aa,1,bb
```

в качестве первой же строки `name` будет считано это все. Вообще, хорошим тоном считается проверять, что возвращает функция ввода... Проще всего - запрашивать разделение пробелами; если это не устраивает - посмотрите в документации, как можно модифицировать спецификатор формата `%s`, чтобы он делал то, что вы хотите. Я для простоты использовал пробелы.

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int num; //размер массива
    int i = 0;

    int* index;//Указатели на массивы с данными
    char** user;
    char** name;

    const int len = 40;  // length of string

    printf("К-во ?");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Введите: Текст число текст\n");

    //динамическое выделение памяти
    index = (int*) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    user = (char**) malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
    name = (char**) malloc(num * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        user[i] = (char*) malloc(len);
        name[i] = (char*) malloc(len);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%s %d %s", name[i], &index[i], user[i]) != 3)
            printf("Wrong input\n");
    }

    printf("%s", user[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        free(user[i]);
        free(name[i]);
    }

    free(index);
    free(user);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `scanf("%s,%d,%s",&name[i], &index[i], &user[i]);`

Не знаю какие должны быть исходные данные, но `%s` вводит строку.
В аргументе `&user[i]` и `&name[i]` - адрес элемента строки со смещением `i`. Последующие символы будут записаны в `user[i+1]` и т.д. На второй итерации все символы кроме первого будут переписаны и т.д. Сомневаюсь что вам это надо.

> `printf("%s", user[0]);`

Тут задан формат для строки, ожидается адрес, а передано число - код первого символа этой строки. Функция пытается обратиться по этому несуществующему адресу и аварийно завершается.

Если вам нужно ввести несколько строк, нужен не один указатель, а массив указателей, динамический `char **user` или автоматический (стековый) `char *user[num]`.